# How can I declare a variable in Swift using the type defined in an AnyClass object?

Tags: objective-c, swift, type-conversion, jsonmodel

In my old Obj-C code I could declare a dictionary whose values were the `Class` types of other classes

```
NSMutableDictionary *Methods = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[Methods setObject:[AuthReturnValue class] forKey:@"Authenticate"];
[Methods setObject:[MyOptions class] forKey:@"GetOptions"];
```

Later, based off of the key, I could assign that `Class` to another variable

(in the header)

```
Class returnType;
```

(in the implementation):

```
returnType = (Class)[Methods objectForKey:methodName];
```

And then I could use this `Class` variable to declare a new variable of that same type (in this case it's using JSONModel and initializing it with an `NSDictionary` from elsewhere)

```
id<NSObject> result;
result = [[returnType alloc] initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)responseObject error:NULL];
```

This was nice and convenient and since JSONModel implements `initWithDictionary`, meant that I could just pull in the `Class` in this way without having to instantiate a particular type.

I can't figure out how to do this in Swift.

For example, this doesn't work:

```
var result: self.returnType.self()
var result: AnyClass = self.returnType.self
```

And a few dozen variants.

How can I declare a variable in Swift to be the `class` defined in an `AnyClass` object? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't instantiate `AnyClass`, as far as I know. You must downcast it to a more concrete type. Additionally, the type you want to instantiate with its metatype, must have a required initialiser. If I understood your example, `AuthReturnValue` and `MyOptions` are both subclasses of `JSONModel`, which has `init(responseObject:error:)` initialiser. Then that initialiser must be required and implemented by every subclass.

```
class JSONModel {
    required init(responseObject: NSDictionary, error: NSError?) {

    }
}

class AuthReturnValue : JSONModel {
    required init(responseObject: NSDictionary, error: NSError?) {
        super.init(responseObject: responseObject, error: error)
    }
}

class MyOptions : JSONModel {
    required init(responseObject: NSDictionary, error: NSError?) {
        super.init(responseObject: responseObject, error: error)
    }
}
```

Now you can do something like this:

```
var methods = [String : JSONModel.Type]()
methods["Authenticate"] = AuthReturnValue.self
methods["GetOptions"] = MyOptions.self
if let returnType = methods["Authenticate"] {
    let result = returnType(responseObject: NSDictionary(), error: nil)
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

The above code works well with native Swift classes, but crashes currently (Xcode6-Beta6) if used with subclasses of Objective-C classes. The workaround is to store metatype values in a `[String : Any.Type]` dictionary and downcast before using. The following example shows how to do this with a subclass of `NSOperation`.

```
class SomeOperation : NSOperation {

}

var dictionary = [String : Any.Type]()
dictionary["some operation"] = SomeOperation.self

if let aClass = dictionary["some operation"] as? NSOperation.Type {
    // Any initializer available in the superclass can be used for
    // creating instances. The compiler will not perform any checks,
    // as it does with native Swift classes, so we must ensure that subclasses
    // actually implement those initializers, either by automatically inheriting
    // or overriding.
    let test = aClass() 
    println(NSStringFromClass(test.dynamicType))
}
```

Comment: This looks like it's probably in the right direction, but I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS (EXC_I386_GPFLT) on the "let result" line. Even if I try and use the returnType constructor with no parameters. Still looking into it but not having luck yet.

Comment: Works for me in Beta6. Have you used exactly the same code? I was also getting  EXC_BAD_ACCESS if the methods dictionary was anything else but [String : JSONModel.Type]. It didn't work with NSDictionary, [NSObject : AnyObject], [NSObject : AnyClass], [String : AnyObject] and [String : AnyClass].

Comment: If I try *exactly* the same code in the JSONodel object, I get an error complaining about missing the usingEncoding parameter (it thinks I'm trying to call a different super.init overload I guess). If I just implement all the required inits (including the one taking in an [NSObject : AnyObject]! and NSErrorPointer argument) I still get the error

Comment: Basically I think if that exact code is working for you in Xcode6b6 and not for me then I must be doing something wrong outside of the code I posted. I'll keep at it and let you know.

Comment: Something that may or may not be clear in my question is that the JSONModel I'm referring to is the open source JSON framework (www.jsonmodel.com). So while the exact code you provide there above works in a playground (where I'm defining a class called JSONModel), it's the using of the *actual* JSONModel that's dying, and its possible that it's either an incompatibility with Swift somehow or there's something special I need to do in order to get it to work but I haven't figured out what yet.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. It seems that the problem exists with any Objective-C class, not only JSONModel from the framework (just tested with  UIView). I'll try to find a solution, if there is one.

Comment: OK, I think I've found a workaround. Create the methods dictionary like this: 

var methods = [String : Any.Type](). And then create your instance like this: 

let result = (returnType as JSONModel.Type)(responseObject: NSDictionary(), error: nil)

Comment: OK your last workaround seems to have done the trick, thanks. You might want to update your answer to reflect that (if you can edit it after I accept - I have no idea how SO works nowadays).

Comment: Updated. Note that I included conditional downcasting as a part of if statement. It's more readable and safer.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented something similar in a small dependency injection framework, and in the end I figure out that the best way to achieve that is by storing a closure instantiating the object.

This is how I would implement the instantiator class:

```
typealias Constructor = (responseObject: NSDictionary, error: NSError?) -> AnyObject

class Instantiator {
    private var instantiators = [String : Constructor]()

    func bindKey<T : AnyObject>(key: String, withType type:T.Type, toInitializer initializer: Constructor) {
        self.instantiators[key] = initializer
    }

    func instanceForKey(key: String, responseObject: NSDictionary, error: NSError?) -> AnyObject? {
        if let instantiator = self.instantiators[key] {
            return instantiator(responseObject: responseObject, error: error)
        }

        return .None
    }
}
```

Then this is how I would use it:

```
class MyClass {
    let x = "Test"
    init(responseObject: NSDictionary, error: NSError?) {}
}

let instantiator = Instantiator()

instantiator.bindKey("GetOptions", withType: MyClass.self) { (responseObject: NSDictionary, error: NSError?) -> MyClass in
    return MyClass(responseObject: responseObject, error: error)
}

let x: MyClass! = instantiator.instanceForKey("GetOptions", responseObject: NSDictionary(), error: nil) as MyClass?
```