# Swift: How did this nil get into my [String: AnyObject] dictionary and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: c#, wcf, dictionary, swift, option-type

I'm using a combination of [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com) and [JSONModel](http://www.jsonmodel.com) in my Swift app to communicate with a .NET WCF service. Everything was working, right up until the point where I made a call that returned `null` values

The problem starts here:

```
if let resultsDict = responseObject as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
    results = AuthModel(dictionary: resultsDict, error: nil)
    ....
```

`responseObject` is parsed from what the WCF service gives back to me (see [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437519/how-can-i-declare-a-variable-in-swift-using-the-type-defined-in-an-anyclass-obje) if you want a little more background). I can cast it to a `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>` collection (have to, actually) and feed it to `AuthModel` which is a subclass of `JSONModel`, but I've found that if the collection contains a .NET `null` object, then `results` is `nil`, which messes up all the code that comes after. And the `null` from the WCF service is a null string in .NET land.

If I do a `print(resultsDict)` on the `resultsDict` object, I see this:

```
[x: <null>, y: 0, __type: Authenticate:#SomeLibrary.Models]
```

In this example, `x` is a string, and `y` is an int from c#/.NET code.

So yeah, it makes perfect sense that the code from JSONModel is not happy when one of the values is nil/null. However,

1. I'm not sure how in the heck a nil/null value is in a non-Optional `AnyObject` object, and
2. I'm not sure how to sanitize/get rid of it.

I can't cast `responseObject` to `Dictionary<String, AnyObject?>`, Xcode complains

I can't replace the particular nul/nill value in the `Dictionary` by iterating over it, Xcode complains (since you can't really work with an `AnyObject` object directly, I think)

I can't just create a second, sanitized Dictionary, since JSONModel apparently needs it to be `<String, AnyObject>` and I run into the same problem as above.

How can I get rid of this null/nil object in my Dictionary?

---

OK, Martin R's comment gave me the hint I needed to come up with some code that could "clean" the dictionary and insert empty strings where there's NSNull/nil/null values (really just NSNull apparently).

```
if let resultsDict = responseObject as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
    var cleanedDict = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
    for r in resultDict {
        if r.1 as? NSObject == NSNull() {
            cleanedDict[r.0] = ""
        }
        else {
            cleanedDict[r.0] = r.1
        }
    }
    results = AuthModel(dictionary: cleanedDict, error: nil)
    ....
```

So I guess Xcode wasn't really telling me I couldn't assign anything to that dictionary, just not the way I was doing it.

I guess the question now becomes - is there a better way to do this? The way I'm doing it is a little bit brute force.

Comment: `<null>` is the description of the `NSNull()` singleton, which is used to represent a "null" from the JSON object. - But is is *different* from nil/null.

Comment: @MartinR ok your comment plus a playground cracked the case. I've added it to the question until/unless someone came come up with a slicker way to do it. If not I'll part out that part and answer my own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a slightly simplified version of your code to replace all `NSNull` 
values in the dictionary by an empty string:

```
if let resultsDict = responseObject as? [String:AnyObject] {
    var cleanedDict = resultsDict // a mutable copy
    for (key, elem) in cleanedDict {
        if elem is NSNull { // NSNull is a singleton, so this check is sufficient
            cleanedDict[key] = ""
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```